# Relatorio em c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, relatório, datatable

Estou tentando desenvolver um relatório(`report`) em `C#` e utilizando o `ReportViewer` para exibição. Estou utilizando o `SGBD` `Postgresql`, e não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados e o `report`, para pegar os dados pois ocorre um erro quando vou adicionar a `dll` do `Postgresql` `ODBC`, já tentei de tudo e mesmo assim não consigo adicionar a `dll` aparecendo a seguinte mensagem:

> "A reference to could not be added. please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component "

então como eu não consigo executar o relatorio dessa forma pensei em um meio alternativo.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu passar um `DataTable` com as informações que eu quero que seja exibida para o `report` e lá ele **exibe** e se sim como posso fazer isso?

Comment: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458434/how-to-set-datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer), [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004307/how-can-i-load-datatable-as-reportdatasource), [link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725634/datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer) e [um passo a passo](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/03/23/mandando-uma-datatable-filtrada-para-o-report-viewer/)

Comment: Ajudou bastante, principalmente o segundo link. obrigado!